# How do I create a single level breadcrumb with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a single level breadcrumb in some applications as shown below:

Home -> Product -> Applications -> Application 1

Now, Applications can have multiple children. So, on hover over 'Applications' I would like a drop down to display all the links to different applications. I'm trying to make it easier for users to hop from application to application.

Any suggestions or links would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As written this question is probably too broad. Do you have any code to show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Is this a regular website or a JavaScript heavy application (ie. are there page reloads or is everything AJAXed)?

Comment: You mean you need a menu, and you want it to look like a breadcrumb trail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to a good tutorial, you'll need to change them from stacking horizontally to vertically or however you want them to look but here's the link:

http://www.kriesi.at/archives/create-a-multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-css-and-improve-it-via-jquery

Comment: It's a breadcrumb trail except for the last item which has a drop down to provide links to other applications